# Which saying means to sell a part as the whole?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains

I'm looking for an English (or foreign saying often used in English) which mean that it is made to believe that part of a thing can achieve what the whole thing only can achieve.

Examples :

**To sell a wheel as if it was a car.** I don't know what a car is but I'm sold its concept (a mean to transport quickly) in the form of one of its part, the wheel. Only later I will realize that I can't do what was claimed without the other parts.
**To sell weights as if they were a full gym.**
**To sell bricks as if they were a house.**
**To sell a spacesuit as if it was a spaceship.**

It's the notion of benefit rather than quantity that is to be expressed.

The real case that brought this question is sellers of online courses (or books) who sell incomplete knowledge to achieve what is claimed. It is different from selling a miracle product.

Comment: Batteries not included . . .

Comment: 'Hype' comes close ... to misrepresent a product, exaggerating its benefits.

Comment: There's something close, but not exactly what you described, in Spanish -- *me dieron gato por liebre.*  They gave me a cat when I was supposedly buying a hare.  I'm sharing this to help people come up with something kind of like that.

Comment: I would suggest that someone is being invited to buy **'half a product'** or a **'partial product'**.

Comment: @NigelJ how would you phrase it ?

Comment: _Online sellers, who advertise books or courses with incomplete knowledge content, are selling a partial product._

Comment: If the seller's goal is to get us to eventually buy the rest of the product/service, it could be part of a (seemingly unethical) "cross-selling/upselling" scheme.

Comment: @NigelJ this is not a saying.

Comment: There is no saying. Therefore one just expresses the concept in English vocabulary and using English grammar. And if used often enough : _it will become a saying, in due course_. That's how language works.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sayings that contrast small with large for effect. We may discount most of them, such as a “a sprat to catch a mackerel”, “spoil the ship for a ha’porth of tar”, “thin end of the wedge” because they do not deliver what you need.

The first I can offer is “a pig in a poke”. The buyer is offered the poke (a bag), but does not really know what is in it (probably a pig, and of unknown quality). Even this saying is not a perfect fit to your specification because I have to argue that the poke, although encompassing the pig, is smaller (in weight or value) than the pig.

> [Dictionary of Scots Language](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/poke_n)
>
> Poke:
>
> A bag or small sack. In commercial use appar. sometimes as a more or less definite measure of a commodity, smaller than a sack

A second suggestion is “buying a pup”, or its corollary “**selling a pup**”, which fits your need. The buyer only gets a small pup when they really needed a grown dog.

> [FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buying+a+pup)
>
> buying a pup:
>
> To buy something that ultimately proves to be worth nothing or less than promised.

Comment: I surmise that a downvoter did not like my Scots reference to *poke*. It is now obsolete in English English but remains commonplace in Scotland.

Comment: I didn't down vote but the concepts of a *pig in a poke* and *buying a pup* do not fit the OP's criteria, A pig in a poke is an unknown, worthless item that may or may not be related to what the buyer intended to purchase, and a pup is something that looks as if it might be what was required but turns out to be the wrong thing - often said of things that don't work as intended.

Comment: @greybeard They are far more respectable reasons for downvoting. Thankyou. But please note I took care to use "suggest" and "offer" rather than assert that I was correct. If we cannot offer and suggest without attracting adverse comment we will be discouraged from helping. It is a difficult question and I doubt we shall get many more responses. Which raises the question: do you have anything better to offer?

Comment: *... rather than assert that I was correct* - perhaps the downvoter saw your caution as being more of a comment than an answer? *Which raises the question: ...* I'm not sure that it does. In the words of Samuel Johnson "You may scold a carpenter who has made you a bad table, though you cannot make a table."

Comment: @Greybeard Oh dear! the imperfections of brief exchanges. I should have said "does *anyone* (you = the readers)  have ..." Thanks for own your patience.

Comment: :) ........................

Answer (score 0):

A word that conveys selling less than you promise is

**shortchange** (v.)

> Deprive of or give less than something due: CHEAT [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortchange)

> To deprive someone of something for which they paid.  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shortchange)

> Treat unfairly by withholding something of value.
>
> *Frankly, to provide anything less than the above requirements is unconscionable, and as a digital camera maker you know better that to
> **short-change** your customers this way.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shortchange)

---

> Chances are good that you'd feel **shortchanged** if you bought a book
> in which the first nine pages were blank. [Bryan Peterson;
> *Understanding Digital Photography*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Understanding_Digital_Photography/FG4g-mEZcEMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=shortchanged%20sold%20empty&pg=PA36&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> However, it could still sit on the dealer's yard for several months before it is actually sold to a customer who is then **shortchanged** on their warranty.
> ["Buyers being **shortchanged** on warranty" at carsguide](https://www.carsguide.com.au/car-news/buyers-being-shortchanged-on-warranty-20723)

> The groups say some Chinese companies routinely **shortchange** their
> employees on wages, withhold health benefits and expose their workers
> to dangerous machinery and harmful chemicals, like lead, cadmium and
> mercury. [David Barboza; "In Chinese Factories, Lost Fingers and Low
> Pay"; *The New York Times*](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/01/05/business/worldbusiness/05sweatshop.html)

Comment: Good attempt. There may be nothing better without being grossly ballpark or prolix.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Yes, I agree.  It's not as blatant as the OP's examples, nor does it necessary mean that (many) well-defined parts were missing. Otherwise we get into *be sold a bill of goods*.